# Вывод шаблона в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

В CodeIgniter для вывода на экран шаблона используется конструкция $this->load->view('шаблон');

Где находится этот метод view? Хотел посмотреть, как там реализован вывод шаблона. Сразу ли там инклюд или буфер. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Метод находится в классе [Loader:443](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L443) и выглядит так:

```
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

А на ваш вопрос отвечает метод `Loader::_ci_load(..)`:

```
protected function _ci_load($_ci_data)
{
    // сократил :)

    /*
     * Buffer the output
     *
     * We buffer the output for two reasons:
     * 1. Speed. You get a significant speed boost.
     * 2. So that the final rendered template can be
     * post-processed by the output class.  Why do we
     * need post processing?  For one thing, in order to
     * show the elapsed page load time.  Unless we
     * can intercept the content right before it's sent to
     * the browser and then stop the timer it won't be accurate.
     */
    ob_start();

    // ещё сократил

    // Return the file data if requested
    if ($_ci_return === TRUE)
    {
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        @ob_end_clean();
        return $buffer;
    }

    /*
     * Flush the buffer... or buff the flusher?
     *
     * In order to permit views to be nested within
     * other views, we need to flush the content back out whenever
     * we are beyond the first level of output buffering so that
     * it can be seen and included properly by the first included
     * template and any subsequent ones. Oy!
     *
     */
    if (ob_get_level() > $this->_ci_ob_level + 1)
    {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    else
    {
        $_ci_CI->output->append_output(ob_get_contents());
        @ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

Чтобы понять, почему `Loader` см [CI_Controller:78](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Controller.php#L78)

Comment: Там вроде нету инклюда шаблона или я его не вижу?)

Comment: Есть, но я сократил много, смотрите [Loader.php:910](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L910),[914](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L914)

Comment: в kohana есть такая конструкция: $this->template->content = $content; свойство content в свойстве template. Как это???

Comment: Так же как и тут - ничто не мешает свойству быть объектом со своими свойствами.

Comment: внутренние шаблоны выводятся буфером. не могу понять, как выводить основной шаблон (базовый) сразу инклюд? или тоже буфер

Comment: Там всё через буфер, но основной сразу куда-то отправляется - смотрите, что делает ``append_output()``, т.к. я с CI не работаю, а лезть так глубоко через веб-интерфейс неохота)

Comment: не обязательно на примере codeigniter. подскажите на примере других или ссылка на простой пример